# Android web view on half screen

Tags: android, webview

I just want to do that but i don't know how. This would be in vertical linear layout. I have searched for 3 hours and haven't found nothing useful yet.

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315332/how-to-create-two-views-in-android-that-use-50-height-each-unless-one-is-small

Comment: @Tomi S: hi I am facing problem like...if I open google.com or say yahoo.com in web view(height=200dp), it show first 200dp blank web view and then open google/yahoo page in full scren...i just try with www.ya.com, it work for me...any help here?

Comment: here in same ...if i click any link then it open a new full screen page instead to open in same 200dp height webview....any idea over this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did it earlier with 2 webviews. I did it by using android:layout_weight to 1 for both the web views and it filled up the screen.

if you want just 1 web view, use another linear layout for the remaining items, and set android:layout_weight="1" to both the webview and the linear layout.

Answer (score 7):

Setting your child View's weights equal to each other should split them evenly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <WebView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for the right example, but nithinreddy answered the first, so i have to check his.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"               
      android:weightSum="1">
```

web browser button

```
 button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_webbrowser);
 button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
 {
    public void onClick(View arg0){
        Intent i = new
        Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
    Uri.parse(“http://www.amazon.com”));
 startActivity(i);
  }
});
```