# Android LinearLayout - warp_content BUT max 50% of screen

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I'd like to set up a vertical `LinearLayout` with two `ScrollView` children. I'd like the top `ScrollView` (containing a `TextView`) to `wrap_content` BUT only until a maximum of 50% of the screen height.

The bottom `ScrollView` should adjust to fill what remains of the screen - always at least 50% of the screen.

I have tried many combinations of `layout_weight` but without success.

Can someone suggest how I do this? Thanks.

---

-------------------- THE ANSWER --------------------------

Here is the way I ended up doing this:
[How to create two views in Android that use 50% height each, unless one is smaller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315332/how-to-create-two-views-in-android-that-use-50-height-each-unless-one-is-small)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a constraintlayout and a guideline at 50% and constrain your scrollviews accordingly.

Have a look here how to use a guideline:
https://constraintlayout.com/basics/guidelines.html